# NSDateFormatter set date to 1970

Tags: ios, nstimer, nsdateformatter

In my `summarydict`, I have a entire called `date_generated`, it looks like : **Sep 22, 2:33 PM**, I want to convert it into a `NSDate` so that I can later feed it into a repeated timer.

So here's my code:

```
ALog(@"Last update time is: %@", [[summarydict objectForKey:@"root"]objectForKey:@"date_generated"]);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLenient:YES];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM dd, h:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[[summarydict objectForKey:@"root"]objectForKey:@"date_generated"]];
ALog(@"Using timezone: %@", [dateFormatter timeZone]);
ALog(@"Last updated time: %@", date);
ALog(@"Current time: %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]);
ALog(@"Next update time: %@", [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:600]);
```

And here's what I got:

```
Last update time is: Sep 22, 2:33 PM
Using timezone: America/New_York (EDT) offset -14400 (Daylight)
Last updated time: 1970-09-22 18:33:00 +0000
Current time: 2011-09-22 18:43:05 +0000
Next update time: 1970-09-22 18:43:00 +0000
```

I understand `NSLog` (my ALog) doesn't care about timezoon, so by displaying it as GMT timezoon is fine, but how can I make the `formatter` think that what I have **Sep 22, 2:33 PM** is for current year? I have `[dateFormatter setLenient:YES];` but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Simple way: add year to your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about this:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2011 %@", [[summarydict objectForKey:@"root"]objectForKey:@"date_generated"]];
NSLog(@"Last update time is: %@", str);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLenient:YES];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy MM dd, h:mm a"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"America/New_York"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"Using timezone: %@", [dateFormatter timeZone]);
NSLog(@"Last updated time: %@", date);
NSLog(@"Current time: %@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]);
NSLog(@"Next update time: %@", [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:600]);
```

Comment: I use this instead of @"2011" so that the app still works next year. :D `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];` and 
`NSString *lastUpdateTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0]], [[summarydict objectForKey:@"root"]objectForKey:@"date_generated"]];`